# Change texts according to other language in template.php

Tags: 7, theming

I have multilangual website ancak my site's footer is in template.php.

Like this:

```
function _site_footer(){
    global $language;

    $output = '<div class="footer_content container_12">
                <div class="item address grid_4">
                   this is a lorem ipsum
                </div>
            </div>
    return $output;
}
```

I want, when I turn my site to other language, get this footer:

```
function _site_footer(){
    global $language;

    $output = '<div class="footer_content container_12">
                <div class="item address grid_4">
                   TESTTESTTESTTEST
                </div>
            </div>
    return $output;
}
```

How can I change it in template.php? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global `$language` variable returns current language object, you can get current language code by `$language->language` property. Example:

```
global $language;
$output = '<div class="footer_content container_12">
                <div class="item address grid_4">
                   this is a lorem ipsum
                </div>
            </div>';
if($language->language == 'en') {
    $output = '<div class="footer_content container_12">
                <div class="item address grid_4">
                   this is a lorem ipsum in english
                </div>
            </div>';
}

return $output;
```

But better way would be using [Render Arrays](https://drupal.org/node/930760)

**2-Solution:** is to wrap the text with [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function. And translate the text by `admin/config/regional/translate` link.

```
function _site_footer(){    
    $output = '<div class="footer_content container_12">
                <div class="item address grid_4">
                   ' . t('this is a lorem ipsum') . 
                '</div>
            </div>'
    return $output;
}
```